# PHP - Smarter Files Referencing

Tags: php, document-root

I have some simple PHP scripts that helps me with small tasks on each of my servers.  I run it via the **CLI** only, since not all my servers have Apache, but I install PHP on all.
I'd like to make it portable, at any time.

Here's my scripting scheme:

```
dir_libs/top.php  (top.php references all my classes and functions)
dir_logs/  (holds logs I may create)
runstats.php  (this is what I initialize from CL)
```

Here's what I have done on one of my servers:

**runstats.php**

```
<?php
require('/home/myuser/public_html/dir_libs/top.php'); // holds functions
require('/home/myuser/public_html/dir_logs/'); // holds logs from my functions

 echo display_stats();
 echo "\n---------------------\n";
?>
```

I obviously need to change the absolute paths, depending on the server, since I don't always keep things the same - even if I clone a virtual machine.

I tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but that appears to need a browser to know where it lies.

Does anyone have a suggestion?
Again, I only intend to run the **runstats.php** from the command-line.

Comment: Use relative paths...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally done in PHP using the `__DIR__` magic constant, like this:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/path/to/file.php');
```

To get to your top-level from a different embedded directory, you can do something like this::

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../dir_libs/top.php');
```

For versions of PHP previous to 5.3.0, you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` in place of `__DIR__`.

For a real-world example, you can look at the Laravel project, which uses a few different tricks in the `.php` files found in the `public` and `bootstrap` directories to reference other files in the project:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v4.1.18

(I've linked to the current version, in case it changes later on.)

Answer (score 0):

Store the path in a constant and then append that on to the file.

```
define('BASE', '/home/myuser/public_html/');
require(BASE . 'dir_libs/top.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

In php 4 the `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` constants hase been added. These should help you!

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php