# how do i use include file with laravel?

Tags: php, include, laravel-4

I am using Laravel and i found a chart lib for my project. This library([libchart](http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/)) is php and it use this:

```
include "../libchart/classes/libchart.php";
```

but if i put this code in my view, i get this error:

```
include(../libchart/classes/libchart.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I dont know how i have to add code in the view or add the library in Laravel.

When i download the library, I have this:

```
libchart
->libchart
->demo
```

Then i paste in:

```
myproject
->app
  ->views
    ->libchart
      ->libchart
      ->demo
```

And `include "../libchart/classes/libchart.php";` is:

```
libchart
->libchart
->demo
  ->LineChartTest.php
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

1. I create a directory called grafico in app.
2. I did this:

   `Route::get('pruebaimagen', function() {
       include_once(app_path() . '/grafico/libchart/classes/libchart.php');
       $data['libchart'] = new Libchart();
       return View::make('template', $data);
   });`

In `return View::make('template', $data);` which type of template i have to use? and i get this error now:

```
Class 'Libchart' not found
```

Comment: Where you have place the library file in?

Comment: It seems you don't have basic knowledge of Laravel. Do you?

Comment: No, i am starting with that.

Comment: I just put up my code for you as a sample. You should adjust it yourself.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question, but based on what I see in your example you should probably be aware of how you can do relative includes with `__DIR__`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21713997/219155

Comment: Sorry if it isnt a answer, but it was a way to run my project. If you knew other way, why you didnt answer my question?, because i didnt know about __DIR__ and its post.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Laravel, you can simplify the process of adding multiple files to your Blade template by utilizing a built-in function provided by the framework.

```
@include('foldername.filename')

@include('filename')
```

They are pure Laravel functions.

Comment: Thank you hemant, this solution is straight forward and still works on Laravel 10

Answer (score 6):

Finally i did it.  Rahil Wazir helped me, and now my project is working.

**My route:**

```
Route::get('pruebaimagen', function() {
    include_once(app_path() . '/librerias/libchart/classes/libchart.php');
    return View::make('demo.LineChartTest');
});
```

**Mi view:**

```
<?php
/* Libchart - PHP chart library
 * Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Jean-Marc Trémeaux (jm.tremeaux at gmail.com)
 * 
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 * 
 */

/**
 * Line chart demonstration
 *
 */

$chart = new LineChart();

$dataSet = new XYDataSet();
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-01", 273));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-02", 421));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-03", 642));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-04", 799));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-05", 1009));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-06", 1406));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-07", 1820));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-08", 2511));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-09", 2832));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-10", 3550));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-11", 4143));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("06-12", 4715));
$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

$chart->setTitle("Sales for 2006");
$chart->render("recursos/demo5.png");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Libchart line demonstration</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
</head>
<body>
    <img alt="Line chart" src="generated/demo5.png" style="border: 1px solid gray;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I added a folder named "librerias" in app and i pasted the library.
Next, I went to:

```
myproject
->composer.json
```

I added this: "app/librerias" in

```
autoload
->classmap
```

Then i runned with cmd: composer dump-autoload and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Don't include your files in view folder.

Create a custom folder in your `app` directory called `anythingFolder` and paste your library there.

Now include your file in your controller method from where you want to use it, like this:

```
public function index() {
    include_once(app_path() . '/anythingFolder/libchart/classes/libchart.php');
    $data['libchart'] = new Libchart()
    return View::make('template', $data);
}
```

Improve the above code as your need

Read this [How to add a library folder to Laravel 4](http://andrewelkins.com/programming/php/how-to-add-a-helper-folder-to-laravel-4/)

Comment: This won't work for me because my employer wants me to `require()` legacy PHP files which themselves `require()` more PHP files using relative paths.  Do you know any way to get back plain old `require()` behavior?

Answer (score -1):

```
@include('foldername.filename')
```

This is the easiest way for find the file and folder in laravel
using this include will find the file, no need to mention big path

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note, that your answer is just a part of that one, hemant kumawat gave already.